# How do I model Revisions of a Post?

Tags: oop

Let's say I need to create a model for some portal like Stack Overflow, and I have a class `Question`.

Is it good idea to have a class like this?

```
public class Question
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int IdCreator { get; set; }
        public List<QuestionRevision> QuestionRevisions { get; set; }
        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

and a class `QuestionRevisions` with fields like `Editor` and `Content`?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like:

```
public class Question

    private Guid id
    private List<QuestionRevision> revisions
    private List<Comment> Comments 

    Question(id : Guid, text : String)
    getRevisions() : List<QuestionRevision>
    addRevision(revision : QuestionRevision) : void
    getComments() :  List<Comment>
    addComment(comment : Comment) : void
```

So the main points here are:

- The guid and questions text are supplied to the object on construction. These should be validated (ie non-null). Consider Builder pattern if `Question` requires more setup.
- A single revision is added to the question
- A single comment is added to the question
- Immutable views of the comments and revisions are accessed via the getters.

I almost never like seeing a class that is purely a holder for a collection, like `QuestionRevisions`. `Question` is a good choice to manage its own revisions and internally use its own appropriate data structure to store them (eg a List is sensible). Without elaborating further on `Editor` and `Content` I'm not sure I can do any meaningful pseudo code for `QuestionRevision`.